# Why were some of my suggested edits reverted by a moderator?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits, moderation

I suggested a bunch of edits and they got approved, but today many of them were reverted by a moderator.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: @BDL They're [not hard to find](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11090142/denis-ivanenko?tab=reputation)

Comment: Providing an example would have made it easier for us to look into. But if you've been mostly doing edits like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19236175/sometimes-aplication-error-black-screen-when-start-with-splash-and-not-open), then the problem is likely that they were not substantial enough.

Comment: You don't just go over old posts to fix a single letter typo in the title. It takes 3 reviewers to look at that useless "improvement". Don't waste their time.

Comment: Oh, I understood. Thanks for your answer. I will do more substantial edits. I`m sorry.

Comment: Are you by any chance searching for common typos and try to fix them? I found 3+ posts with "thead"->"thread" and 3+ "nomalized"->"normalized".

Comment: Also, try to focus on better posts. [Fixing typos](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48465145/revisions) on closed questions without resolving the close-worthy issues is a waste of time for you and the reviewers.

Comment: @rene I think it's even more worrying that those edits were approved. If the reviewers had done their job properly this shouldn't have gotten to the point were 90 edits needed reversing.

Comment: @ivarni yeah, that we have reviewers in the suggest-edit queue that need a stern talking to is a given ... sadly enough.

Comment: The usual advice here is "don't polish a turd." In other words, there's not much point in editing a post if it will still be bad after your edit. Try to focus on posts that are either already decent but just need some cleaning up, or ones where you can fix all the major problems they have.

Comment: That question was nearly incomprehensible (output from Google Translate?). It is better to select posts that are comprehensible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sorry, I meant to send you a private message earlier, but I was distracted handling other things.

A majority of your recent suggested edits were correcting a single typo, and you did not fix other glaring issues with the post contents. See the linked duplicate for more info.

Comment: Okay, I asked this question just to clarify the reason for rejection. I did not know that such corrections are forbidden and that inspectors need to do so many robots for approval.

Comment: @DenisIvanenko It's not that they're forbidden altogether, but users with <2000 rep need the edit to be reviewed, resulting in more work for other users on minor edits. By making more substantial edits it makes that time worthwhile. When you have >2000 rep edits like this are less of a concern (if not done in bulk)